ODBC tables that are tabs in an Excel spreadseet: how are they defined and named so that Word can see them?
I have MS-Word and Excel (MS Office 2019, if it matters). I am using Word to produce sheets of pretty labels to stick on a calendar. The labels are images, not text. The page contains 6 × 15 labels. I used to do this by painstakingly pasting an image onto each label, but I got tired of doing that. So instead I am using Word's mailmerge.
Now each label has a field (in the sense that Quick Parts uses the term field) like this:
{ INCLUDEPICTURE { IF TRUE "{ MERGEFIELD Filename }" } \d}

I then use an ODBC connection to an Excel file to pick up the value of Filename  for each label from the mailmerge table, and substitute it in the INCLUDEPICTURE field, so that the corresponding image appears on the label. This may be inelegant, but it works well.
Word obtains the list of filenames from Excel using the ODBC SQL statement
SELECT * FROM `'Public Holidays$'`

and Public Holidays is the name of a tab in the Excel spreadsheet.
If I want to provide a different list of filenames to mailmerge, I can do
Mailings | Select Recipients | Use an existing list... | +Connect to a New Data Source.odc
| Open data source: OLE DB Database Files (OK)
| What kind of data source?: ODBC DSN (Next)
| Excel Files (Next) | Select the database: (path to Excel file),
☑ Connect to a specific table:

and in the list of tables I see several names of the form 'Public Holidays$' that point to tabs of the same name in the spreadsheet (without the trailing $ sign).
Next I added a new tab to the same spreadsheet.
What I expected was that the new tab would appear (after closing both MS-Word and Excel and restarting) in this list of tables. But it didn't. After futzing with it for an entire morning, I discovered that sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't.
The original connection to the Excel spreadsheet was set up by an MS-Word wizard. I was bumbling around mystified, and can't remember exactly how it was all made to work. I can't reproduce what I did.
What I want to know is, how does a tab in the Excel spreadsheet, that is an ODBC DSN table, come to appear in the list of ODBC tables with a $ appended, and why does that sometimes happen and sometimes not? What special thing do I have to do to make a new tab appear in the list? I suspect that it has something to do with the tab, because a tab that I create by duplicating the initial one appears on the list of tables, but if I simply insert a new tab, that tab does not appear in the list of tables. So it seems, anyway.
I have already discovered that if I set up a named range in the Excel spreadsheet, that name appears in the list of tables (without a $ appended) and doing that makes the practical issue go away.
But I want to understand how some Excel tabs appear in the list as tables with $ appended to the name, and others not. Long experience with Windows leads me to expect that resource names ending in $ are magic. In this case, what is the magic?

(Changed from my original post)
As far as I can tell, this problem results from a Microsoft error related to the specific route you are using to connect to the Excel data source.
The simplest workaround is almost certainly to select the .xls (or .xlsx) directly in the Select Data Source dialog rather than clicking the New Source... button in that dialog. That does mean that you will need to locate the .xls if it isn't in your My Data Sources folder.
If you do that, once you have selected the .xls/.xlsx, what happens depends on whether or not you have checked the Word->File->Options->Advanced->General->Confirm file format conversion on open option .
If you have not checked it, Word will try to open the workbook using the appropriate OLEDB provider. The OLEDB provider has been Windows Word's default provider for Excel files for over 20 years and is typically easier to work with than any of the ODBC options. However, there may be reasons why you need to use the ODBC driver (e.g. the two providers/drivers format numbers differently), in which case there is yet another connection procedure you can use
If you have checked it, Word will display the Confirm Data Source dialog box. If the file is a .xlsx file, you should see just one option, OLE DB Database Files . Select that, and Word should present a list of sheets and named ranges. If the file is a .xls file, you may see one or more ODBC options and a DDE option as well. But still, select the OLE DB option and take it from there.
There are in essence at least 3 different routes you can take to connect via ODBC/OLEDB.
The OLEDB route just uses the appropriate OLEDB provider, which has a dialog that displays the objects that that provider "sees".
There is another similar route that just uses the appropriate ODBC driver. That has a more confusing dialog where you (a) may have to reselect the file name again, or the dialog may select the wrong file, and (b) you have to click its Options... button and SELECT the SYSTEM TABLES checkbox to ensure that the dialog displays all the objects that it can see. I can go into that if you really need to continue using ODBC.
These OLEDB and ODBC dialogs display different lists from each other, and may also display different things depending on whether the workbook is open in Excel or not. (e.g. the ODBC driver displays the names of hidden sheets if the workbook is open in Excel, but not if it isn't).
The route that you have been using does yet another thing - it opens the workbook using the OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers, and that uses the appropriate ODBC driver for Excel. This route displays its own list of objects that it can see. But I think there is an error, because it only seems to be able to "see" sheet names that have spaces in them. (I suspect it is actually "sheet names that cause the driver to surround the name with single quotation marks"). So it's really not a very helpful route to take in the general case.
The following is detail that someone may find useful if they want to dig deeper.
I did try to look at exactly what the OLE DB provider, the plain ODBC driver, and the OLEDB provider+ODBC driver were doing to identify the various objects in the Excel workbook. As far as I can tell, the OLE DB provider sees all the qualifying objects as having type "TABLE". Qualifying objects include

worksheets
Excel Names that correspond to ranges in the workbook that have more than one contiguous cell. Possibly, the definition is more restrictive than that, e.g. it may need to be a rectangular group of cells. But a Name that idetifies a formula rather than a range isn't included, a Name that identifies a single cell isn't included, and a range that identifies a list of non-contiguous cells isn't included.

In contrast, the ODBC driver sees two types of thing:

sheets that have names that do not need to be quoted. These have type "SYSTEM TABLE"
all other qualifying objects (as above). These have type "TABLE"

AFAICS, this is not what the Microsoft documentation says about the Excel ODBC driver. It suggests that all sheets have type SYSTEM TABLE and Ranges have type TABLE. I suspect the documentation is just wrong.
When you are in the "OLEDB+ODBC" dialog, the list shows the TABLE names and omits the SYSTEM TABLE names.
But, when you are in the old ODBC dialog and use the Options button  to select what you see, the only thing that appears when you just check the TABLE option are range names that are defined at Workbook level (rather than being defined as associated with a Worksheet). If you check the SYSTEM TABLES option as well, everything else appears. If you then uncheck the TABLES option, the entire list disappears. So that does not really help us to understand how that dialog is deciding what types of object it is seeing. It's possible that all these dialog boxes and lists are generated by software that is not communicating directly with the ODBC driver, and that the only way to find out what is going on would be to write a C/C++ program to invoke the ODBC API directly.

Thank you for your patient, comprehensive and above all very useful reply. My apologies for responding to the earlier version of your answer, but it took me more than a day to assemble my responses and, of course, in that time, I did not refresh the screen, so as not to lose what I had already done.
